# numpy: How to express a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, join

Say I have the following logical relationships:

```
# ANIMALS
cat = [hobbes, tigger, garfield]
dog = [lassie]
frog = [kermit, hypnotoad]

# HABITATS
tree = [cat, frog]
river = [dog, frog, turtle]
house = [cat, dog]
```

There will never be duplicates within a set. I want to match them into pairs of `(animal, habitat)`

```
(hobbes, tree)
(garfield, tree)
(tigger, tree)
(kermit, tree)
(hypnotoad, tree)
(lassie, river)
(kermit, river)
(hypnotoad, river)
(hobbes, house)
(garfield, house)
(tigger, house)
(lassie, house)
```

If this were SQL, it would be something like....

```
CREATE TABLE animal (animal_name, animal_type);
CREATE TABLE habitat_to_animal (habitat_type, animal_type);

SELECT
    animal.animal_name,
    habitat_to_animal.habitat_type
FROM animal
JOIN habitat_to_animal
    ON animal.animal_type = habitat_to_animal.animal_type
```

They're stored in numpy arrays (actual arrays are `numpy.int32`) like so:

```
# animals are sorted by animal_kind
animal_kind = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'frog']
animal_name = ['hobbes', 'tigger', 'garfield', 'lassie', 'kermit', 'hypnotoad']

# habitats are sorted by habitat_type
habitat_type = ['tree', 'tree', 'river', 'river', 'river', 'house', 'house']
habitat_animal = ['cat', 'frog', 'dog', 'frog', 'turtle', 'cat', 'fish']
```

What is the *fastest* way to do this in numpy if arrays are very large (millions of entries each)?

EDIT: This must be numpy only (no Pandas or other libs). As far as data cardinality goes, imagine both sets are ~10 million "animals" and ~100 million "habitats", and 200 million actual pairs output (most habitats will be empty, and some will have 5-10 animals). That means that generating the full cross product and filtering is a no-go. As are any loops; data is way too big.

Real arrays are integer IDs and have nothing to do with animals or habitats, but it's easier to read this way =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want selection capabilities like SQL, I'm going to suggest you think about Pandas for handling the data. It can happily store Numpy arrays, but you have very flexible filtering options for slicing the data lots of different ways.

For what you're asking, I don't know if you even need to do much more than just make the DataFrame and iterate over it. Here's an example that tries to stick close to your SQL example:

```
import pandas as pd

animal_kind = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'frog']
animal_name = ['hobbes', 'tigger', 'garfield', 'lassie', 'kermit', 'hypnotoad']

habitat_type = ['tree', 'tree', 'river', 'river', 'river', 'house', 'house', 'house']
habitat_animal = ['cat', 'frog', 'dog', 'frog', 'turtle', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog']

df_animal = pd.DataFrame(data=animal_kind, columns=["animal"], index=animal_name)
habitat_to_animal = pd.DataFrame()
habitat_to_animal["animal"] = habitat_animal
habitat_to_animal["habitat"] = habitat_type

for i in range(len(habitat_to_animal)):
    animal, habitat = habitat_to_animal.loc[i]
    names = df_animal[df_animal.animal == animal].index
    for name in names:
        print(f"({name},{habitat})")
```

This produces your list as requested. I think it will scale fairly well, but there are 3-4 different ways to iterate over rows in Pandas, and the fastest way depends on the data and what you're doing to it.

Comment: I'd love to use Pandas, but it's been explicitly rejected by the boss.

Comment: What?? Scipy, Numpy, and Pandas are essentially the Holy Trinity of scientific computing in Python. To forbid the use of the de facto standard for data structures is insane.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [113]: animal_kind = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'frog']
     ...: animal_name = ['hobbes', 'tigger', 'garfield', 'lassie', 'kermit', 'hy
     ...: pnotoad']
     ...: 
     ...: habitat_type = ['tree', 'tree', 'river', 'river', 'river', 'house', 'h
     ...: ouse', 'house']
     ...: habitat_animal = ['cat', 'frog', 'dog', 'frog', 'turtle', 'cat', 'fish
     ...: ', 'dog']
     ...:
```

turn them into arrays:

```
In [115]: kind,name,type,animal=[np.array(x) for x in (animal_kind,animal_name,h
     ...: abitat_type, habitat_animal)]
```

Make a table matching the kind.  This could be large.

```
In [116]: kind[:,None]==animal
Out[116]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False]])
```

Find that matches (`True`):

```
In [117]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[117]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]),
 array([0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 7, 1, 3, 1, 3]))
```

Use those indices to select items from the other arrays:

```
In [118]: np.stack([name[_[0]],type[_[1]]])
Out[118]: 
array([['hobbes', 'hobbes', 'tigger', 'tigger', 'garfield', 'garfield',
        'lassie', 'lassie', 'kermit', 'kermit', 'hypnotoad', 'hypnotoad'],
       ['tree', 'house', 'tree', 'house', 'tree', 'house', 'river',
        'house', 'tree', 'river', 'tree', 'river']], dtype='<U9')
```

That pairing can be transposed:

```
In [119]: _.T
Out[119]: 
array([['hobbes', 'tree'],
       ['hobbes', 'house'],
       ['tigger', 'tree'],
       ['tigger', 'house'],
       ['garfield', 'tree'],
       ['garfield', 'house'],
       ['lassie', 'river'],
       ['lassie', 'house'],
       ['kermit', 'tree'],
       ['kermit', 'river'],
       ['hypnotoad', 'tree'],
       ['hypnotoad', 'river']], dtype='<U9')
```

Here it's grouped by name.  To group by habitat, use the transpose of [116]

```
In [123]: I,J = np.nonzero(_116.T)
In [124]: np.stack([name[J],type[I]], axis=1)
Out[124]: 
array([['hobbes', 'tree'],
       ['tigger', 'tree'],
       ['garfield', 'tree'],
       ['kermit', 'tree'],
       ['hypnotoad', 'tree'],
       ['lassie', 'river'],
       ['kermit', 'river'],
       ['hypnotoad', 'river'],
       ['hobbes', 'house'],
       ['tigger', 'house'],
       ['garfield', 'house'],
       ['lassie', 'house']], dtype='<U9')
```

### iterative

An iterative list solution would be:

```
In [188]: alist = []
     ...: for t,a in zip(habitat_type, habitat_animal):
     ...:     for k,n in zip(animal_kind,animal_name):
     ...:         if k==a:
     ...:             alist.append([n,t,k])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [189]: alist
Out[189]: 
[['hobbes', 'tree', 'cat'],
 ['tigger', 'tree', 'cat'],
 ['garfield', 'tree', 'cat'],
 ['kermit', 'tree', 'frog'],
 ['hypnotoad', 'tree', 'frog'],
 ['lassie', 'river', 'dog'],
 ['kermit', 'river', 'frog'],
 ['hypnotoad', 'river', 'frog'],
 ['hobbes', 'house', 'cat'],
 ['tigger', 'house', 'cat'],
 ['garfield', 'house', 'cat'],
 ['lassie', 'house', 'dog']]
```

Since `animal_kind` is sorted, we should be able to shorten the inner loop by iterating on just the 'next' group of kinds.  That's a bookkeeping detail that I'll leave to you (unless I get bored ).

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out. My worry is that there will be hundreds of millions -- really, billions, split up over several nodes -- of rows. So the cross product based approach feels like it would get insanely big/slow. On the plus side, these are integers and not strings.

Comment: Yes, that's the price you pay for the privilege of using the numpy whole-array building blocks :)  An alternative is a more iterative matching written in something like `numba`, but I won't go there.

Comment: Yeah, (100 million * 100 million) bits is more than a petobyte of booleans. Anything that doesn't use the fact taht these rows are already sorted is untenable.